# webstandard theme not rendering?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

An application we're developing for a customer is running more or less fine on our internal development servers (V 8.5.3 with UP1 and FP5 as well as a secondary V 9). Our development is done using V 9 designer clients.

Yesterday we pushed a test version onto the customer's server (V 8.5.3 FP5 / UP1). The result rendered by their server however is completely different from what we get from our servers. It turns out that only custom style sheets are rendered while everything that usually should be coming from the server's webstandard theme is completely missing: no xsp.css, xsp_ie.css and the likes. Thus the pages are completely unusable: tabbed panels are rendered as standard  elements, rich text editors are completely broken, just to name a few things.

We had the local admins check the server file system: webstandard theme appears to be there, and accessible to everyone.

Has anyone ever come across something like that? In 4 years of developing Xpages I've never seen something like that, at the moment I'm completely clueless in what to try next.

I really hope that this is just a minor flaw easy to be resolved.

Lothar

Comment: Check the HTML source and see if the "missing" files are referenced but just not loaded. It could be internet site substitution rules that are blocking the files.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Turned out that it's much simpler than that (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hilarious: for security reasons the customer's admins deleted all files from the server's file system that they thought weren't needed. For some reasons they left the themes but removed all resources like css and js files (including all dojo dirs). No, I won't tell any names.
Lesson learned: never just assume a customer's setup to be fully functional until this fact is properly proved ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the installation? I have seen servers that were upgraded the wrong way by copying the data directory, then upgrading and then moving back the data old directory, thus overwriting some important files or even loosing important files and directories...

Comment: good point; I'll have them check that (unfortunately, I don't have access to the FS myself...)

Comment: should be an easy one by checking the template names on that machine